# Communicating with Modbus using Bluetooth in iOS / Swift 5

Tags: swift, bluetooth, core-bluetooth, modbus, ios-bluetooth

I'm communicating with a Modbus protocol using Bluetooth and getting a delay of about 500-700 milliseconds whereas I'm expecting it about 40-50 milliseconds.

Here are the steps which I’m following:

1. I’m trying to discover the hardware device in the iPhone and make a connection with it.
2. As soon as the connection established, I got the service and list of characteristics.
3. Now, I’m trying to use the write characteristics and getting the response in about 500 milliseconds

Can anyone help me out? I’m stuck very badly here.

Here is the code block which I'm using:

```
func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) {
    let df : DateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    df.dateFormat = "E dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSSS"
    let dateString = df.string(from: Date())
    print("...Getting Values.............\nTimeStamp: \(dateString)\n\n")
    print("didUpdateValueFor ========> \(characteristic), \(String(describing: error))")
    self.createPackage(type: .recieveResponse)
    if let error = error {
        print("Failed… error: \(error)")
    }
}    

func writeCharacteristicValue(peripheral: CBPeripheral, data: Data, char: CBCharacteristic, type: CBCharacteristicWriteType) {​​​​​​​​

        peripheral.writeValue(data, for: char, type: type)

    }​​​​​​​​

func writeDataToBlePeripheral(characteristic: CBCharacteristic, byteArray: [UInt8], connectedPeripheral: CBPeripheral) {
    let bytes : [UInt8] = byteArray
    let data = Data(bytes)
    print(data)

    let df2 : DateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    df2.dateFormat = "E dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSSS"
    let dateString2 = df2.string(from: Date())
    print("...Aftert data conversion Sending.............\nTimeStamp: \(dateString2)\n\n")
    

BLEManager.getSharedBLEManager().writeCharacteristicValue(peripheral: connectedPeripheral, data: data, char: characteristic, type: .withResponse)

    let df1 : DateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    df1.dateFormat = "E dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSSS"
    let dateString1 = df1.string(from: Date())
    print("...After Sending.............\nTimeStamp: \(dateString1)\n\n")
}
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to show relevant code?

Comment: @Paulw11: I've updated the question and add the function which I'm using for writing the data on the my Bluetooth device.

Comment: When you say it takes have a second to get the response, so you mean the delegate call to `didWrite` or do you mean some other response back to the peripheral?  How many bytes are you sending?

Comment: @Paulw11: We are sending 8 bytes. Here is the calling method: writeDataToBlePeripheral (characteristic: self.writeCharactrestics!, byteArray: [1, 4, 0, 51, 0, 1, 193, 197], connectedPeripheral: self.connectedPeripheral!)

Comment: And the answers to my other questions?

Comment: @Paulw11 after writing this byte array to peripheral using writeDataToBlePeripheral then after 500-700 milliseconds my delegate call didupdateValue So I am trying to find out why it's taking too much time to call my delegate.

Comment: What queue is your delegate using? The main queue?

Comment: @Paulw11 I am using iOS core Bluetooth CBPeripheral default delegates. I think It's call in main queue

Comment: @SandeepM I am also facing the similar issue. Have you got any solution for this?